# Issue with Class and Public Function returning data from MYSQL database

Tags: php

I am trying to use Class with Public Function and my query is coming back with following error:

> "Notice: Undefined variable: articles in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\index.php on line 21"

I have done a print_r to show the result from class and everything looks correct.

> "Array ( [0] => Array ( [article_id] => 1 [article_title] => Title [article_content] => Content [article_timestamp] => 2019-02-02 13:33:03 ) )"

On my class function, I have tried placing the query into variable then return that variable out of class, but error message.

If I bypass the class function, and place the query result into `$Articles` then it works.

line 1-6 /Index.php

```
 <?php
 include_once('includes/article.php');
 $Article = new Article;
 $Articles = $Article->fetch_all();
 print_r($Articles)
 ?>
```

line 17-21 /Index.php

```
 <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>         
 <ol>
 <li><a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>"><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></a> - <small><?php echo date('l F jS, Y', strtotime($article['article_timestamp'])); ?></small></li>
 </ol>
 <?php } ?>
```

line 5-8 /includes.php

```
 class Article {
     public function fetch_all() {
        return DB_query("SELECT * FROM articles");
     }
 }
```

line 51-70 /includes.php

```
 function DB_query($query, $params = []) {
     $conn = DB_connect();
     if ($params)
     {
         $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
         $types = str_repeat('s', count($params));
         $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
         $stmt->execute();
         $result = $stmt->get_result();
     } else {
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
     }
     if ($result)
     {
         $result = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
         return $result;
     } else {
         return mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
     }
 }
```

The Result should be `echo $article['article_id']` will return ID, `echo $article['article_title']` will return title and finally `echo date('l F jS, Y', strtotime($article['article_timestamp']))` will return date.

Comment: I see $Article and $article used. Maybe case sensitivity could be causing a problem?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable. **The variable name is case-sensitive.**

You need to use either `$Articles` or `$articles` in both places.